# updatePassword error: auth/requires-recent-login

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update a user's password using Firebase Authentication. I noticed that the user has to be recently logged in to change the password. So I added the function  `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, but the error persists. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    try {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            updatePassword(user, data.newPassword).then(() => {
                // Update successful.
                console.log('Update successful.');
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log("e", e)
                signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, data.oldPassword).then(() => {
                    // Signed in
                    console.log('Signed in');
                    updatePassword(user, data.newPassword).then(() => {
                        // Update successful.
                        console.log('Update successful.');
                    }).catch(e2 => {
                        console.log("e2", e2)
                    })
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log("error", error)
                })
            })
            setTimeout(resolve, 500)
        });
        reset();
        enqueueSnackbar('Update success!');
        console.info('DATA', data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

It always logs "Signed In", but I get an error in e2 that auth/requires-recent-login (so even after signing in again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Firebase Authentication, there are some operations that are considered sensitive. Changing a user’s password is indeed a security-sensitive operation that requires a recent login from the user. So for such an operation, you should reauthenticate the users.

There are however two solutions for solving this problem, you either reauthenticate the user by asking for the credentials or you can sign the user out and let it authenticate again.

Comment: In my code I did just that - reauthenticated the user using signInWithEmailandPassword function (I ask the user for the "old" password and their email). However, even after the function I have the same error. Could you take a quick look at the code if there is something I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not the right function, you should use [reauthenticateWithCredential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#reauthenticatewithcredential), right?

Comment: It works with reauthenticateWithCredential().